# Array remove didn't work on click listener?

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

I have an **add** and **eject** buttons on my app. In the **add function** I can add items to an array but when I press the eject button to take out items from the array it doesn't work. I can't figure out why this is happening.

Below my current code:

This is my **add button** function and it is working well.

```
        holder.customView.imageButton4.setOnClickListener {
            addedCount += 1
            holder.customView.adet_text.text = "x$addedCount"

            var urun = holder.customView.urun_text.text
            var fiyat = holder.customView.fiyat_text.text

            var addedData = SepeteGidenUrunlerModel(
                urunEklenen = urun.toString(),
                fiyatEklenen = fiyat.toString()
            )

            FirstDetailActivity.sepeteEklenenUrunler.add(addedData)
        }
```

Here my **delete** button:

```
        holder.customView.imageButton5.setOnClickListener {

            if (addedCount > 0) {
                addedCount -= 1

            }

            holder.customView.adet_text.text = "x$addedCount"

            var urun = holder.customView.urun_text.text
            var fiyat = holder.customView.fiyat_text.text
       
            var cikarilan = SepeteGidenUrunlerModel(
                urunEklenen = urun.toString(),
                fiyatEklenen = fiyat.toString()
            )

            FirstDetailActivity.sepeteEklenenUrunler.remove(cikarilan)
        }
```

And here my data model : `class SepeteGidenUrunlerModel(val fiyatEklenen: String = "", val urunEklenen: String = "")`

Why is this not working?

Comment: Make `SepeteGidenUrunlerModel` a data class so it will have a proper `equals` function generated for it so it can be removed using the newly created equivalent instance.

Comment: It is working like a charm. Can you write answer so I can check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your model class doesn't have a proper `equals` function defined, it is compared by referential equality, which means the new instance you create in this click listener will not match anything already in your list, so nothing can be removed with it.

Declare the model class `SepeteGidenUrunlerModel` as a `data class` so it will have an `equals` function generated for it automatically under the hood.

Comment: So if I remove equals from my model, can it be working? My model have empty equal strings, is this equals you said to answer?

Comment: What do you mean by "remove equals"?

Answer (score 1):

When you do  a .remove in array you do it by reference not by value, you should reference the original item when you do the .remove()

When you do this you're creating a new object of type SepeteGidenUrunlerModel wich isn't the same object in the list

```
var cikarilan = SepeteGidenUrunlerModel(
            urunEklenen = urun.toString(),
            fiyatEklenen = fiyat.toString()
        )
```

What you can do is first get the element by reference and then remove that object from the list. (Something like this, it can contain some syntax errors since I dont't do Kotlin)

```
  var urun = holder.customView.urun_text.text
  var fiyat = holder.customView.fiyat_text.text
   
  var urun = holder.customView.urun_text.text
  var fiyat = holder.customView.fiyat_text.text
  
  var cikarilan = FirstDetailActivity.sepeteEklenenUrunler.find(it.fiyatEklenen == urun.toString() && it.urunEklenen == fiyat.toString())

  FirstDetailActivity.sepeteEklenenUrunler.remove(cikarilan)
```

Comment: My array type also SepeteGidenUrunlerModel. Like var `sepeteEklenenUrunler = ArrayList<SepeteGidenUrunlerModel>()` . When I try to use $ sign to remove object it is also didn't work.

Comment: @mehmett edited the answer with a possible solution

Comment: The question has been answered but I will keep your answer in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var cikarilan = SepeteGidenUrunlerModel(
            urunEklenen = urun.toString(),
            fiyatEklenen = fiyat.toString()
        )

        FirstDetailActivity.sepeteEklenenUrunler.remove(cikarilan)
```

You are removing the item which you created right above, Java/Kotlin tries to find the item where the equals method tells them that it's the item you mean and then deletes it.

You haven't defined a equals method so it tries to find it "by reference", which means you can never find the item that was just created, because they are always in a different place in memory.

Either override the equals method to include something like a id or rewrite your remove logic to remove the last item for example (you need to find the item that you mean in some way, then you can remove it).

Comment: I understand but when I try to write for loop like :                ` for (i in sepeteEklenenUrunler){
                    if(i.urunEklenen == urun.toString()){
                        sepeteEklenenUrunler.remove(i)
                    }
                }`. It is getting error also. I really don't know how can I solve it.